# recommendation for really high precision attitude measurement sensors

Tags: sensors, research

I am new in this field, I am looking for some high precision gyroscopes and accelerometers for attitude measurements.The precision requirement is around 0.2~0.5 deg/s dynamic.
    I have done some digging myself, not a single integrated MEMS sensor can do that without costing too much. So some heavy math is needed but that's fine.I need to make sure the prefect sensors are chosen, the budget is less than 100USD.
    can any one help, thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine is senior developer at Infineon technologies for automotive applications. He told me that the best Inertial-MEMS for the automotive applications (which is basically your price target) are provided by BOSCH.
After a quick search, I found the SMI130 which has pretty good signal-to-noise ratios. In addition this chip is available for 13$.

Comment: thanks @TobiasK, this might be the best MEMS sensor that combines gyroscope and accelerometer. how about some individual components?